# Преобразования string в массим

Tags: javascript, jquery

У нас есть строка виду:

```
["5f02a238f331c8d97d034ea75ffc5980.jpg"]["c9c73e530e271bf09c9c3ed468ba4045.jpg"]["db3b5058f7b53c1bb82baf83a3d25d7f.jpg"]["0ce6f72a1608673f1ad9bbd5657b7257.jpg"]["5c088f2fdfe5c4bbdf2fbb98fe6affa0.jpg"]["b18de21683cfba726f31f66878e9d027.jpg"]["80deb2befce558aad5152d1b8cf7b216.jpg"]["6e0553d5dcd9d5fc713370ea9781f128.jpg"]
```

Надо преобразовать строку в массив виду:

```
["5f02a238f331c8d97d034ea75ffc5980.jpg","5f02a238f331c8d97d034ea75ffc5980.jpg","5f02a238f331c8d97d034ea75ffc5980.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = '["5f02a238f331c8d97d034ea75ffc5980.jpg"]["c9c73e530e271bf09c9c3ed468ba4045.jpg"]["db3b5058f7b53c1bb82baf83a3d25d7f.jpg"]["0ce6f72a1608673f1ad9bbd5657b7257.jpg"]["5c088f2fdfe5c4bbdf2fbb98fe6affa0.jpg"]["b18de21683cfba726f31f66878e9d027.jpg"]["80deb2befce558aad5152d1b8cf7b216.jpg"]["6e0553d5dcd9d5fc713370ea9781f128.jpg"]';
str = str.replace(/\]\[/g, ",");
var data = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Блин , чето у мня слабинка по js на ету тему, где можно узнать побольше о преобразовании строк!А пофакту спасибо решил проблему!

Comment: @JuniorCoder https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String